# Correct way to store UI-specific settings in MVVM pattern

Tags: mvvm

I am fairly new to MVVM. I am writing an application in which user creates a study for a physics simulation, inputs some data, runs the sim, and then views the results in graphs and tables. The application needs to have Save As / Open functionality to save the study into a single file and load it back after restarting the application.

Now, trying to keep application concerns and UI concerns separate, the Study class (which is basically a data structure), - the Model in MVVM - stores data with user inputs, study settings, simulation results, etc. ViewModels are generated dynamically when various windows or controls are opened, using relevant data from the Study. Meanwhile, View only deals with UI stuff. So all concerns are separate, just like it should be in MVVM. When Study is saved (serialized into file) and later loaded back into application, this works fine.

However, there are some data display or UI customizations that user might change, such as:

- Window position, size, docking
- Table column/row creation, ordering, sizing
- WPF GridView resizing using GridSpliter
- Created graphs/plots with their relevant settings

All these things are either View or ViewModel concerns, and are specific to current UI implementation. They should be preserved as well when saving/loading Study, but they clearly don't belong in Study class. So where should I store all these customizations without violating MVVM concern separation?

Since I do need to save Study into a single file for user convenience, one idea I had was to store all these customizations in the ViewModels, wrap both Study instance and ViewModel instances into a wrapper class and serialize it into a file when Save As is called. When Open is called, deserialize this file, load up deserialized Study instance, and as for ViewModels - check if currently running application UI implementation matches the one used when file was saved; if yes - load it in, if not - create new ViewModels. But this feels more like a hack than a proper solution.

Can anyone advise? How is this typically solved?